# Responsive Menu and Slider Height Question

Tags: css, wordpress

My website is this: http://laserchecks.outpostphx.com/

and the mobile responsive menu doesn't fit right. Also, the top blue area above the slider is too big for some reason now. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix?

The theme is by FOX

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
.menu_slide #nav_button_alt{margin:2px 0px 0px 10px;}   
#mobile-menu{width: 100%;    transform: translateX(100%) !important;}
```

}

Please use this code in css file.

Comment: Thank you! It fixed the mobile slider, but my mobile menu still isn't displaying properly for some reason?

Comment: I added that code but on iPhone the menu text is still not displaying? Do you have any other recommendations? The cart icon and layout is fixed, but mobile navigation menu is quite messed up.

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 767px){
 .slided_body{
  transform: translateX(-80%) !important;
  z-index: 99;
 }
 .mm_open{
  transform: translateX(20%)!important;
 }
}

Please use this code in you CSS